# my code work fine when compiled with maven command but gives build error when configure and run with jenkins, please help what could be the error

Tags: selenium, maven, jenkins, testng

Unknown lifecycle phase "mvn". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or :[:]:. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy.

Comment: It would help if explained how you are invoking `mvn`. Pipeline /Freestyle, invoke top-level maven target, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The Maven command in Jenkins is set incorrectly.

Use something like `mvn clean deploy` as Maven command. You may have to skip the `mvn` if it is already implicit.